# Stored procedure to delete some entries and return their IDs

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I want to create a stored procedure or database function to delete some entries and return their IDs to the client. I started off with this `FUNCTION`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FixHangingCarriers ()
RETURNS @returntable TABLE
(
    ID_Plant INT NOT NULL,
    ID_ChargeCarrier INT NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN;
    -- Declare a temporary table
    DECLARE @EntriesToDelete TABLE (
        ID_ChargeCarrier INT NOT NULL,
        ID_Storage INT NOT NULL,
        StoredOn DATETIME2(2) NOT NULL
    );

    -- Select all the entries that should be deleted
    INSERT INTO @EntriesToDelete
    SELECT
        ID_ChargeCarrier,
        ID_Storage,
        StoredOn
    FROM dbo.CurrentStorage
    WHERE ID_StorageType = 4
    AND StoredOn < DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GetDate());

    -- Return immediately, if there is currently nothing to delete
    IF (SELECT 1 FROM @EntriesToDelete) = 1
        RETURN;

    -- Delete hanging entries
    DELETE ccs
    FROM dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage ccs
    INNER JOIN @EntriesToDelete d ON
        d.ID_ChargeCarrier = ccs.ID_ChargeCarrier AND
        d.ID_Storage = ccs.ID_Storage AND
        d.StoredOn = ccs.StoredOn;

    -- Prepare return table
    INSERT INTO @returntable
    SELECT cs.ID
    FROM @EntriesToDelete d
    INNER JOIN dbo.ChargeCarriersCurrentlyInPlant cp ON
        cp.ID_ChargeCarrier = d.ID_ChargeCarrier;

    -- Return deleted entries to caller
    RETURN;
END;
```

Obviously this doesn't work, because SQL functions cannot delete anything. I wanted to change it into a `PROCEDURE`, but then I saw, that procedures naturally seem not to be able to return a table. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: _"...to delete some entries and return their IDs..."_ Can't you just use **[`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** clause?

Comment: Stored procedures don't return tables, but they do have result sets. Anything you `SELECT` in a procedure (that doesn't go `INTO` something) will become part of the result.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Does that mean, that, if I would call `SELECT * FROM @returntable;`, it would just return that as a result?

Comment: Any reason you don't just try it and see? You can even do that sort of thing [online](https://dbfiddle.uk/) these days. But yes, that's what it means. The only drawback is that results from stored procedures are harder to consume from within T-SQL -- if that's an issue there's [lots of background material on that](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html). Clients will be able to consume stored procedure result sets just fine though, as they would any other query.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The procedure will be called periodically via Entity Framework only. I'll try it.

Comment: Add an `OUTPUT` clause to the `DELETE` statement to return a result set of deleted data from the proc. You don't need `@returntable`

Comment: What you have above is a `FUNCTION`, not a `PROCEDURE` The 2 are very different objects, and the former cannot perform DML statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, this seems like all you need is this:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.FixHangingCarriers 
AS BEGIN

    DELETE ccs
    OUTPUT deleted.ID
    FROM dbo.ChargeCarrier_Storage ccs
         INNER JOIN CurrentStorage cs ON cs.ID_ChargeCarrier = ccs.ID_ChargeCarrier
                                     AND cs.ID_Storage = ccs.ID_Storage
                                     AND cs.StoredOn = ccs.StoredOn
    WHERE cs.ID_StorageType = 4
      AND cs.StoredOn < DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE());
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution is ingeniously simple!

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two choices.

One is to return the rows as part of a SELECT statement as suggested. However, if you want to consume those in the next bit of T-SQL, you can't just SELECT from a table returned by a stored procedure.

Lots of people ask for a command like SELECT * FROM (EXEC someproc) but that doesn't exist.

What you can do instead is to define a table variable like this:

```
DECLARE @OutputIDs TABLE
(
    OutputIDKey int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    OutputID int
);
```

Then you can use an INSERT EXEC to get the values:

```
INSERT @OutputIDs (OutputID)
EXEC dbo.MyStoredProcedure;
```

And then you have the IDs in the table variable to do what you want with. (Note: you could also do that with a temporary table but it isn't as good an option)

The other option is to use an OUTPUT parameter to the stored procedure. However, you'd need to pack all your IDs into a string (perhaps a comma-delimited list) before you return it. You then use a function to unpack the string back to a set of IDs. (If you're on SQL Server 2016 or later, you could use the STRING_SPLIT function).

The trick with using OUTPUT parameters is that you have to define it as OUTPUT when you are calling the procedure, and in the header of the procedure itself. Here's the skeleton code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoSomething
@OtherParameter int,
@IDsToOutput nvarchar(max) OUTPUT,
@YetAnotherParameter int
AS
BEGIN
...
END;
```

And then when you call the procedure, you do this:

```
DECLARE @OutputIDs nvarchar(max);

EXEC dbo.DoSomething @OtherParameter = 1, 
                     @IDsToOutput = @OutputIDs OUTPUT,
                     @YetAnotherParameter = 2;

SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@OutputIDs, ',');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you this different approach!